# Java not compiling changes in my code

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have this problem with both Netbeans 8.0 and Eclipse.  In Eclipse when I can write a Java program and it will compile and run fine.  Then I can make a change to the source and when I run it again sometimes the old version of the code without the change in the one that is run.  If I hit run a second time the new version is run.

In NetBeans I get a different error the second time I try to run updated code. "Could not find or load main class".  This happens sometimes when I make changes to the source.  I think this might have a similar cause to what is going on in Eclipse.  In both cases the problems are intermittent and difficult to reliably reproduce.

I am using JDK 7 but before I was using JDK 8 and had the same problem.

Comment: In eclipse: Do you have checked Project -> Build Automatically?

Comment: _Could not find or load main class_? Do you have one?

Comment: in NetBeans you can right click on your Project and open the "properties" – under *run* you can make all settings for the program to run and there you can define your "Main Class" (use "Browse...").

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about netbeans but in eclipse if you change code and you don't save before launching sometimes it executes the old code. So ctrl+s or hit the button save before launching every time. It seems that the run and save command are not issued by eclipse in the same order so it runs and saves at the same time but runs the old code.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have the rights to comment right now so here it goes, i faced the similar problem when i was using net-beans 8.0. the main reason behind this problem is your classpath.("could not find or load main class").one way to ignore this problem is to set the classpath as the current directory(which can be done by using " set classpath=*;".). kindly revert if this doesn't solve your problem.
p.s: try it to compile with dos.
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin" and you are good to compile.

and in eclipse, when the present src code has some errors.. it tend to compile and run the previous code.